# pandas resample with nonstandard intervals

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe with, say minute frequency data:

```
time price
2:00  10.0
2.01  10.3
2.03  9.9
…
```

And I want to resample it to an hourly frequency *with the extra twist that the hours begin and end at 15 minutes past the hour.*

Now, there is a clunky way of doing it: first:

`df.time = df.time - timedelta(minutes=15)`

and then:

```
df.resample('1H', loffset=timedelta(minutes=15)).mean()
```

Is there something cleaner/more efficient, though?

Comment: That looks pretty clean to me. Its only two lines. Can you go into more detail about how you want it to be efficent? Is it slow? Would you rather have it be one line?

Comment: @EdekiOkoh I would think this is common enough for there to be an "offset" option. Also, there is a slight cheat, since there really should be a third line resetting the time back to what it was before.